# Need help troubleshooting button click in Selenium

Tags: asp.net, selenium

**Update:**

After further investigation, actually what's happening is when the checkbox is checked using jquery, the next step is to click the button to save. Well, for some unknown reason, the checkbox is unchecking itself.

Here's the jquery to select the checkbox:

```
            string jsStmt = @"
$(function(){

$(':checkbox').filter(function(){
    return $(this).parent().next('td').text() === 'Label to look for';
}).prop('checked', true);

});
";


            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_driver;
            js.ExecuteScript(jsStmt);
```

I can see the checkbox get checked, then when the dialog closes I can see it get unchecked?

**OP:**
Button click event for Selenium testing has been working for a while. All of a sudden, it's not working anymore. Only possible change was some 3rd party css change but I don't know what it could've been.

The button is kind of buried in layers, however, there's a checkbox that gets checked by Selenium that is still working fine, and it's the reason why the button needs to be clicked.

I can debug, and see that Selenium is finding the button. It appears that the button gets clicked but the postback event doesn't occur.

I can stop execution right before the click event and open developer tools and manually type in the statement to click the button, AND that works!

I even tried executing the click with JavaScriptExecutor with no luck.

I am so lost why it's Not firing postback event.

Comment: Which driver are you using?

Comment: Please post the code you are using along with any error messages, etc. Also post the relevant HTML or preferably a link to the page.

Comment: I am using IEDriverServer.exe 2.45.0.0 and I've tried on latest 3.1.x.x and doesn't work there either.

Comment: @Rod if you're using `selenium` my guess is you want the test to behave like a user. Why not use `selenium` to check the box instead of `jquery`? IMO using the `IJavaScriptExecutor` should be extrememly rare or not used at all in `selenium` tests. Using `selenium` will more accurately reflect a user clicking on the checkbox, where using `javascript` might allow you to do actions that a user wouldn't be able to do, making you think everything is fine when the test passes.

Comment: @Rod If you can provide some `html` for the checkbox and submit button, I'd be glad to help with some `selenium` code to click it.

Comment: @mrfreester you're absolutely right. That worked. Thank you.

Comment: @mrfreester although, I wonder why the jquery quit working, I think there was knockoutjs involved but not sure. Anywho, if you put your answer as an answer i'll gladly mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, try clicking the checkbox using an `IWebElement` instead of `javascript`.

I would suggest avoiding using `IJavaScriptExecutor` as much as possible in selenium tests as it can lead to performing functions the user wouldn't actually be able to do with simple interactions, or having those functions behave differently than you would expect because the execution path is different than what a user would do if they just clicked something.

I think that's what you're running to in this case where you're trying to mark the box as `checked`.